# Why were there traps outside of Colonia?

Tags: plot-explanation, colonia

In Colonia (2015) once Lena, Daniel and Ursel get outside the prison, we see multiple deadly traps set in the woods. Considering this territory is no longer part of the prison and could be accessible by anyone, why are there these deadly traps?

Answer (score 1):

It was a safeguard on the part of the Colonia's security. Considering that Colonia Dignidad was isolated and cut off from the outside world, it was highly unlikely that someone (other than the ones trying to escape) would stumble upon the traps.